# why iptables giving error when using with --src-range

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall

I am using iptables v 1.4.8 and used following command but getting one error message on terminal

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 10.0.4.92-10.0.4.99  -j DROP

modprobe: module 'ip_tables' not found
```

Then after this when i am using

```
iptables-save
```

then also seeing the same error.

also when using

```
iptables -L
```

same error is coming to terminal with the result of `iptables -L` , I am thinking using the `--src-range` option giving me this error as I tried other command but not having this error.

But it is working fine but why this error is coming to terminal I can figure out.

Kindly give some solution

Comment: Which linux distro ?

Comment: no distro as it is for embedded system and only linux kernel is used 2.6.28.10 version of kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Your current kernel wasn't built with iptables support (`CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES`), or the module has been erased.